# Test properties that injected by React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that renders a button if a property `errorMessage` is not `null`.

```
class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // Injected by React Redux
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
    resetErrorMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  renderErrorMessage() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props;
    if (!errorMessage) return null;

    return (
      <p id="error-message">
        <b>{errorMessage}</b>{' '}
        <button id="dismiss" onClick={this.props.resetErrorMessage()}>
          Dismiss
        </button>
      </p>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        {this.renderErrorMessage()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The property injected by React Redux:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import App from '../components/App/App';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  resetErrorMessage: () => ({
    type: 'RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE',
  })
})(App);
```

As you can see I also have `resetErrorMessage` that clears `errorMessage`:

```
const errorMessage = (state = null, action) => {
  const { type, error } = action;

  if (type === RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE) {
    return null;
  } else if (error) {
    return error;
  }

  return state;
};
```

How can I test my component and say if I click the button then button hides or if `errorMessage` is not `null` button shows?

I want to get something like this:

```
const props = {
  errorMessage: 'Service Unavailable',
  resetErrorMessage,
};
it('renders error message', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('#error-message').length).toBe(1);
    wrapper.find('#dismiss').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('#error-message').length).toBe(0);
  });
```

But now my problem is that if I simulate click to dismiss button - error message doesn't hide.

Comment: Are you talking about a testing framework ?

Comment: You render the component with the property set however you want. One of the main advantages of React is that it allows you to do so--export an unconnected version of the component and test normally. The logic behind the property value itself is tested in your Redux tests.

Comment: @DaveNewton are you mean I shouldn't test click on the button?

Comment: @rel1x I may have misunderstood your question/problem. The callback for `onClick` should be just that-a reference to the callback. You're currently calling `resetErrorMessage` and using the result of that as the click handler, which almost certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in the previous question you deleted, if you want to test button clicks your best bet would be to call the 'unconnected' component. If you want to test the connected component, then you have to pass a mockstore into it like so.

```
 const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} store={store} />);
```

So import the app in your test and just pass the resetErrorMessage function as a mocked function, such as what you do with jest.

```
const resetErrorMessage = jest.fn(() => {});
const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} resetErrorMessage={resetErrorMessage} />);

wrapper.find('#dismiss').simulate('click');
expect(resetErrorMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

My advice would be to only test the connected component when you want to manipulate directly from store changes.